I want to hide <iframe> tag and video source url. Show a video only in a div
I want to hide the  tag and video source URL in my HTML code. Show a video only in a div. This is my code below.
I can give you two screenshots to understand more.
To add my code I can see 
But I want like 


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const videoContainer = document.getElementById('video-container');

            // Function to dynamically embed the YouTube video
            function embedYouTubeVideo(videoId) {
                // Create the iframe element
                const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.setAttribute('width', '560');
                iframe.setAttribute('height', '315');
                iframe.setAttribute('src', `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`);
                iframe.setAttribute('title', 'Embedded Video');
                iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
                iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture');
                iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');

                // Append the iframe to the video container
                videoContainer.appendChild(iframe);
            }

            // Call the function to embed the YouTube video with the specified video ID
            embedYouTubeVideo('XlMlg5ZAMgw'); // Replace with your YouTube video ID
        });
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Embedded YouTube Video Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Can you share with us why you need to hide them? Because they can't be hidden from the Developer Tools/in your program.

A client requirement.

That's not possible but there's a workaround. If you don't want the user to see the video source URL when the user open the developer tools, you can add a JavaScript that when the user open the dev tools, the video URL will be removed or replaced by a dummy URL. Then set it back to original URL when the dev tools closes.
